# Oro CRM not ignoring parameters.yml for database during installation

Tags: orocrm

I'm trying to install ORO CRM 4.2 on CentOS 7. I enter the database parameters after composer install. Then I can check in parameters.yml that the user/password are Ok, but for some reason when I execute the console installation command `php bin/console oro:install --env=prod --timeout=200` It tries to use root@localhost credentials to connect to MySQL.

```
In AbstractMySQLDriver.php line 112:

  An exception occurred in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for u
  ser 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)


In Exception.php line 18:

  SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using pas
  sword: NO)


In PDOConnection.php line 38:

  SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using pas
  sword: NO)
```

I checked and rechecked that there's no "root" or "localhost" configured in the parameters.yml file, but I don't know why is trying to use them

Answer (score 2):

Parameters are cached. You can run `rm -rf var/cache/*` to clear the cache. Then restart the installation.

Comment: This solved my issue.